# jQuery: How can I select two list items in the same position in different lists?

Tags: jquery

I have a table of contents displayed twice in the same web page. When a user clicks the link in one list, I'd like to change the class of the same link in both lists.

My code already adds/removes the class when clicking the list items, so I'd just like the two lists to match up. So when List Item 1 in the first list changes to class ".active", so does List Item 1 in the second list.

**Link to fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/4b7ag69f/

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $('ul li a').removeClass();
  var index = $(this).parent().index();
  $('ul').each(function() {
    $('li', this).eq(index).find('a').addClass('clicked')
  })
})
```

```css
.clicked {
  color: orange;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $('a').removeClass('clicked');
  var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
  $("ul").each(function(){
    $($(this).find("li")[index]).find("a").addClass('clicked');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the index and then apply that class to the other list using `nth-child()` selector:

```
  var index = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
  //$(this).addClass('clicked');
  $('ul li:nth-child('+index+') a').addClass('clicked');
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4b7ag69f/2/)